# Best way to package kivy application for ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, kivy

There is no info in the official doc of kivy for packaging kivy application for ubuntu. https://kivy.org/docs/gettingstarted/packaging.html

I have tried this also but it didn't work for me.
http://bitstream.io/packaging-and-distributing-a-kivy-application-on-linux.html

I am having dependencies of python3 and kivy.

I want to get the binaries that can be directly clicked and used with no installations.
Can anyone help.

Comment: I think the recommended method is pyinstaller, the instructions should be very similar to those for windows.